# Problem in connecting the front end api with the spring boot app

Tags: javascript, reactstrap

This is the error which I am getting in "console" on "inspect" code in the browser.

user-service.js:5

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')
    at signUp (user-service.js:5:1)
    at submitForm (SignUp.js:57:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
```

Here is the code for SignUp.js

```
    import { Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Container, FormGroup,Form,Label,Input,Button,Row,Col } from "reactstrap";
import Base from "../components/Base";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signUp } from "../services/user-service";
const SignUp = () => {
    
  
  const [data,setData]=useState   //here we are doing array destructuring,here "data" is a variable which will give us 
                                  //the initial object and to change this object we are using the  "setData"
  ({

    name:'',
    email:'',
    password:'',
    about:'',


  })

  const[error,setError]=useState({
    errors:{},
    isError:false
  })


  //handle change


//handleChange function will take event as parameter,here we are basically passing event "e" of  "onChange" Listener
  
//dynamically setting the values
const handleChange=(event,property)=>{
    setData({...data,[property]:event.target.value})
    
  }


//resetting the form
  const resetData=()=>{
    setData({
      name:'',
      email:'',
      password:'',
      about:'',

    })
  }

  //submitting the form
  const submitForm=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(data);

    //data validate

    //call server api for sending data
    signUp(data).then((resp)=>{

      console.log(resp);
      console.log("success log");
    }).catch((error)=>{

      console.log(error)
      console.log("Error Log")

    });

  };
  
  return(

       <Base>
         
         <Container>

          <Row className="mt-4">

            {JSON.stringify(data)}

          <Col sm={{size:6,offset:3}}>

          <Card color="primary" inverse>


<CardHeader>

    <h3>Fill information to regitser!!</h3>
</CardHeader>

<CardBody>

    { /*Creating Form*/ }

     <Form onSubmit={submitForm}>

        {/* Name Field */}

      <FormGroup>

        <Label for="name">Enter Name</Label>
        <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Here"
        id="name"
        onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'name')} //here onChange is a listener and e is a event which we have passed inside 
                                        //handleChange,now number of times values will change that many times value
                                        //of e will tell us the no. of changes.
        value ={data.name}                                
           />                            
        </FormGroup>

          {/* Email Field */}

      <FormGroup>

         <Label for="email">Enter Email</Label>
         <Input
         type="email"
        placeholder="Enter Here"
        id="email"
        onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'email')}
        value={data.email}

        />


       </FormGroup>


         {/* Password Field */}

      <FormGroup>

                <Label for="password">Enter Password</Label>
                <Input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Enter Here"
                id="password"
                onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'password')}
                value={data.password}

            />


        </FormGroup>


          {/* About Field */}

      <FormGroup>

                    <Label for="about">Enter About Yourself</Label>
                    <Input
                    type="textarea"
                    placeholder="Enter Here"
                    id="about"
                    style={{height:"200px"}}
                    onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'about')}
                    value={data.about}

                    />


                    </FormGroup>

                    <Container className="text-center">

                       <Button outline color="light">Register</Button>
                        <Button onClick={resetData} color="secondary" type="reset" className="ms-2">Reset</Button>


                    </Container>



     </Form>

</CardBody>

</Card>
          
          
          </Col>


          </Row>


         </Container>
       
       </Base>

    );
};

export default SignUp
```

the code written below is for user-service.js

```
import { myAxios } from "./helper";

//we have used export here so that we can use the signUp api/function in our signUp component
export const signUp = (user) =>{
    return myAxios
    .post("/api/v1/auth/register",user)
    .then((response) => response.data);
};
```

Comment: What is the `myAxios` you are importing in user-service.js from the helper module? It seems to be undefined so probably you are not exporting it correctly.

Comment: I am importing myAxios from helper.js and code of helper.js class is this:            
      import axios from "axios";
     export const BASE_URL='http://localhost:9090';
     export const myAxios= axios.create({
    baseURL:BASE_URL
});

Comment: If you `console.log` `myAxios` in user-service.js when calling `signUp` what gets printed?

Comment: I tried to do console.log(myAxios); in user-service.js but I am still getting the same error which I got earlier.

Comment: `I tried to do console.log(myAxios);`. And what did it log?